# Fog AWS: How to get account ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, fog

Using *fog* library of ruby how can I get the account ID of the current authentication? I use `access_key_id` and `secret_access_key` to authenticate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this info through `get-caller-identity` API of STS service.

In Ruby:

```
Aws::STS::Client.new(your_oprions).get_caller_identity[:account]
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no such call to get raw accounID in all the api. However theres a nice trick to do it thru `get_user` call from IAM API

If you are calling AWS API you are necesarily using an IAM user keys to do so. Every IAM user has an ARN (amazon resource name) that ARN should contain the AccountID on it.

I don't know how using fog but using AWS-SDK you can use [Aws::IAM::CurrentUser](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/IAM/CurrentUser.html)

```
require 'aws-sdk'
i = Aws::IAM::CurrentUser.new(region: region, credentials: credentials)
puts i.arn
```

You should see the ARN of the caller user, with the AccountID on it. Also thru aws-cli console application you'll get the same answer using

```
aws iam get-user --query "User.Arn"
```

Perhaps there's something similar in Fog